# A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `ClassName.value'

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, compare

These simple two line code giving me error `A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property`ClassName.value'` . i just follow tutorial from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807179/how-to-convert-string-variables-to-c-sharp-char-arrays). I am using this code in unity3d.

// Input string.

```
string value = "Dot Net Perls";
```

// Use ToCharArray to convert string to array.

```
char[] array = value.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: show your real code instead of dummy

Comment: Are "value" and "array" non-static fields in your class? If so then you cannot do it this way. You can initialize the array in constructor instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to access `value` in the class scope like this:

```
class Foo
{  
   string value = "Dot Net Perls"; 
   char[] array = value.ToCharArray();
}
```

This is not allowed. You can only declare class members in the class scope, other statements that includes instance members should be written inside of a method.Even the initalization at this scope is just a syntactic sugar. When you do:

```
string value = "Dot Net Perls";
```

Compiler will move the initalization to the constructor.

Comment: *other statements should be written inside of a method* That's not true. If you mark both the fields as `static` it will work without any problem.